# Swift 3 URL() not making phone call as I wanted?

Tags: swift3, call, ios10

I am trying to get my button to call the taxi when it's clicked by the user. I know that the openURL method has been replaced by the URL() method however, as I tried it on my app the button doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. Can anyone tell me where I did wrong?

here's my code:

```
    @IBAction func callTaxiButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let url = URL(string: "telprompt://10293019203912090")!
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

thank you for your time and help

Comment: are you trying in simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your application in simulator then you will not find anything happening. Try to run on actual device if you are using simulator.